# Double buffer getting colors a little off

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using an inherited TableLayoutPanel with DoubleBuffered set to true.  The problem is that my background color of the TableLayoutPanel is AliceBlue, but any group boxes are a noticeably darker blue--enough to stand out.  If I take a screen shot and paste (e.g. mspaint), the screen shot shows them being the same.  The group box doesn't stand out in the screen shot.  If I turn off DoubleBuffered, I don't see these group boxes standing out as being a darker blue.

It's impossible for me to post a screen shot, because any screen shot will show the group box background the same as the background.

How can I use double buffering and not have group boxes show up a different brightness than the parent's background?

Comment: Not sure I get it - are your colors off at run-time or just when you take a screenshot and paste it in MSPaint? Have you tried with SnagIt?

Comment: Colors in a screen shot are correct; run-time and design time are incorrect.  How can a screen shot be different that what is shown on the screen?

Comment: With or without double buffering, a border is showing up around labels that isn't there in screen shots.

Comment: I think I solved it.  Appears to be a remote desktop bug and instead of docking my laptop, I am using RDP when at my desk.

Comment: Changed my color from 32bit to 24bit in my remote desktop session and that fixed the issue.  Interesting that less bits is better in this case.